# How can I speed up this c# HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, httpwebrequest

I have a c# script task in an SSIS job that calls an API for the purpose of Geocoding.  The API is proprietary and works something like this, receives request, takes address string, then attempts to string match to a huge list of addresses (millions) and if it cannot find it, then go out to another service such as google and get geodata info.

As you can imagine this string matching takes up a lot of time per request.  Sometimes it's as slow as one request per min, and I have 4M addresses I need to do this for.  Getting any dev work on the API side of things is not an option.  To give a better picture of the process here is what I'm doing currently:

I pull a list of addresses from database (about 4M) and put it in a datatable and set variables:

```
        // Fill c# datatable with query results
        sdagetGeoData.Fill(dtGeoData);

        // check to ensure datable has rows
        if (dtGeoData.Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
            // if datatable has rows, for every row set the varible
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in dtGeoData.Rows)
            {
                localID = row[0].ToString();
                address = row[1].ToString();
                city    = row[2].ToString();
                state   = row[3].ToString();
                zip     = row[4].ToString();
                country = row[5].ToString();

                // after varaibles are set, now run this method to post, get response and insert the string
                GetGLFromAddress();
            }
        }
```

**`GetGLFromAddress()`** works like this:

Take the variables from above and form the JSON.  Send the JSON using "`POST`" and `httpWebRequest`.  Wait for request (time consuming). Return request. Set new variables with the return. Use those variables to update/ insert back into database, THEN loop through the next row in original datatable.

It's important to understand this flow because I need to be able to keep the **`localID`** variable with each request so I can update the correct record in the database.

Here is **`GetGLFromAddress()`**:

```
    private void GetGLFromAddress()
    {
        // Request JSON data with Payload
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            // this takes the variables from your c# datatable and formats them for json post
            var jS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var newJson = jS.Serialize(new SeriesPost()
            {
                AddressLine1 = address,
                City         = city,
                StateCode    = state,
                CountryCode  = country,
                PostalCode   = zip,
                CreateSiteIfNotFound = true
            });


            //// So you can see the JSON thats output
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newJson);
            streamWriter.Write(newJson);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

        }

        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                // javascript serializer... deserializing the returned json so that way you can set the variables used for insert string
                var p1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                // after this line, obj is a fully deserialzed string of json  Notice how I reference obj[x].fieldnames below.  If you ever want to change the fiels or bring more in
                // this is how you do it.
                var obj = p1.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(result);

                // you must ensure the values returned are not null before trying to set the variable.  You can see when that happens, I'm manually setting the variable value to null.
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj[0].MasterSiteId))
                {
                    retGLMID = "null";
                }
                else
                {
                    retGLMID = obj[0].MasterSiteId.ToString();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj[0].PrecisionName))
                {
                    retAcc = "null";
                }
                else
                {
                    retAcc = obj[0].PrecisionName.ToString();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj[0].PrimaryAddress.AddressLine1Combined))
                {
                    retAddress = "null";
                }
                else
                {
                    retAddress = obj[0].PrimaryAddress.AddressLine1Combined.ToString();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj[0].Latitude))
                {
                    retLat = "null";
                }
                else
                {
                    retLat = obj[0].Latitude.ToString();
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(obj[0].Longitude))
                {
                    retLong = "null";
                }
                else
                {
                    retLong = obj[0].Longitude.ToString();
                }
                retNewRecord = obj[0].IsNewRecord.ToString();

                // Build insert string... notice how I use the recently created variables
                // string insertStr = retGLMID + ", '" + retAcc + "', '" + retAddress + "', '" + retLat + "', '" + retLong + "', '" + localID;
                string insertStr = "insert into table        " +
                                   "(ID,GLM_ID,NEW_RECORD_IND,ACCURACY)    " +
                                   " VALUES                                       " +
                                   "('" + localID + "', '" + retGLMID + "', '" + retNewRecord + "', '" + retAcc + "')"; 


                string connectionString = "Data Source=; Initial Catalog=; Trusted_Connection=Yes";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(insertStr);
                    cmd.CommandText = insertStr;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection  = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        {
            string insertStr2  = "insert into table  " +
                               "(ID,GLM_ID,NEW_RECORD_IND,ACCURACY)    " +
                               " VALUES                                       " +
                               "('" + localID + "', null, null, 'Not_Found')";
            string connectionString2 = "Data Source=; Initial Catalog=; Trusted_Connection=Yes";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString2))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(insertStr2);
                cmd.CommandText = insertStr2;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection  = connection;
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I have attempted to use **`Parallel.Foreach`**, I had issues with the variables.  I'd like to have multiple requests ran, but to retain each instance of the variable per request if that makes sense.  I have no way to pass the **`localID`** to the API and return it, or that would be ideal.

Is this even possible?

And how would I need to structure this call to achieve what I am after?

Essentially I want to be able to send multiple calls, to speed up the entire process.

EDIT: added the code for `GetGlFromAddress()`.  Yes, I am a newb, so please be kind :)

Answer (score 0):

Put all your data in an array and you could call more than one request at a time, it is best to use multi tasks or Async Methods to call API.

Comment: So if I put all my request strings in an array, lets say only 2 for example, A and B.  I send A and B through, and B returns first.  How do I ensure I update the correct record in the database?  Does Async have a way to ensure things are returned in the correct order? what about multi-threading?